# MySQL: Out of range, but the column isn't last?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, range, out

After an awful lot of time figuring out what's wrong with my code, I decided to go ahead and ask for help. As of right now this is the code which's causing the error:

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `message` FROM `notifications` WHERE `active`='1'");
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    int index = 1;
    if (rs.next()) {
        while (!rs.isLast()) {
        messages.add(rs.getString(index));
        index ++;
        } 
        if (rs.isLast()) {
        messages.add(rs.getString(index));
        }
    }
    return messages.toArray(new String[messages.size()]);
} catch (Exception localException) {
    if (localException instanceof NullPointerException) {
        /* ignore for now */
        localException.printStackTrace();
    } else {
        localException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error is telling me that the column is out of range, but when I look into my database it's not.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Inside the

```
 if (rs.isLast()) {
    messages.add(rs.getString(index));
    }
```

The index will be 2, in this statement, but your resultSet only contains one column.

When you say `rs.getString(2)` it is going to grab the value associated with the 2nd column.

Should be :

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `message` FROM `notifications` WHERE `active`='1'");
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
int index = 1;
while (rs.next()) {
    messages.add(rs.getString(index));
}
```

Note: A best practice is to get the value based on column name instead of index. I believe you thought that getString(index) accessed the row, and calling it by the column name would clear that up for you.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `message` FROM `notifications` WHERE `active`='1'");
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
String column = "message";
while (rs.next()) {
    messages.add(rs.getString(column));
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thanks for lesson, it is well appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The [`isLast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isLast%28%29) method only determines if you're on the last row, not the last column.  The way that you're using `index` is to iterate over all columns on the same row.

The way to determine the number of columns is to get the `ResultSetMetaData` object from the `ResultSet` and get the number of columns from it, using the [`getMetaData()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29) on the `ResultSet` and the [`getColumnCount()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) on the `ResultSetMetaData`.  Then you can use that to loop through your columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you have just one column `message` in the SELECT clause. Remove `index++` from your java code to get rid of the exception because `rs.getString(index)` is trying to get value of column number 2 which does not exists in the query result.